# Reset/Recover forgotten deploy password in Meteor

Tags: meteor

How to Reset/Recover forgotten deploy password in Meteor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way of doing this is contacting meteor and prove that project is your's.

refer [this answer in github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/314)